# How to use "find" in a string search to locate a starting position to the left of the search result

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, find

Forgive me for probably posting the dumbest of questions, but Python newbee here.  I am on the chapter of regex and it seems easy to extract an email address out of a file. Problem is that I have not yet understood how to accomplish this using "normal" code.  I can locate the position of the "@" using .find and then the end of the email address by finding the next space after the "@".  But how to move the search "to the left" of the "@"? There is no lfind...

It is probably the simplest of things, but I have searched so many sites now that I gave up and created an account here.  I thought by going negative I could maybe move to the left, but wrong. Would be very grateful if someone could turn the lightbulb on for me. Thanks a bunch!

Example:

```py
data = "From random-text myemail@gmail.com Sat 21:19"
atpos = data.find("@") 
end = data.find(" ",atpos)
start = data.find(" ",**???**,**???**)
address = data[start:end]
print(address)
```

Comment: it might be better to clarify what exactly your hoping to acheive. so sample input and expected output. people can help explain issues in your current code but might also suggst a different approach

Comment: trying to understand the basics of .find. It seems that using .find you can locate something like the @ and then locate another position to the right based on the first value. No finding a position to the left of the search result. My goal in the example was to slice out the full email address

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the string by spaces and then for each word check if has the `@` string. If it does then you can split the word by the `@` string to get the part to the left and right

```py
data = "From random-text myemail@gmail.com Sat 21:19"
for text in data.split():
    if "@" in text:
        left, right = text.split('@')
        print(f'The email starts with "{left}" and is in the domain "{right}"')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The email starts with "myemail" and is in the domain "gmail.com"
```

**UPDATE**

if you truley do want to do this with index positions and find. Then you already know how to find the position of `@`, and you know how to search the first space after the `@` by specifying your start index.

the documentation of find specifies that it finds the lowest index. However we can use `rfind` to find the highest index i.e the last occurnace in the string.

> **string.find**(s, sub[, start[, end]]) Return the lowest index in s where
>   the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in
>   s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and
>   interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.
>
> **string.rfind**(s, sub[, start[, end]]) Like find() but find the highest
>   index

So using rfind we can find the last instance of space in the string. if we pass 0 as the start (so starting at the beginning) then pass the index of `@` as the end then it will find the index of the last space char between the start of the string and the `@` symbol. we then want to add 1 because we dont want the index of the space but the index after it.

```py
data = "From random-text myemail@gmail.com Sat 21:19"
#get the index of the @
at_index = data.find('@') 

# get the first index of space starting after @
right_index = data.find(' ', at_index) 

# get the last index of space starting from start but not exceeding index of @
left_index = data.rfind(' ', 0, at_index) + 1 

print(data[left_index:right_index])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
myemail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much. A bit more advanced than what I have learned so far, only know {} these from dictionaries until now. Looks like you can use them to call on them in the loop above. Just trying to understand the basics of .find for now. It seems that using .find you can locate something like the @ and then locate another position to the right based on the first value. No finding a position to the left of the search result. My goal in the example was to slice out the full email address.

Comment: the `{}` in the print statements are syntax in pythons f-string you can read up about it and how to use it. it just lets you declare variables inside your string. if you do just want the whole email then inside the for loop just do `if '@' in text: print(text)`

Comment: I have updated y answer to explain how you can do this just using find and rfind for the index positions

Comment: This really helped and opens up now ways.  Still so much more to learn just on the basics.  So really appreciate the time you spent and the detail you went into helping me understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = "From random-text myemail@gmail.com Sat 21:19"
data_list = data.split(' ')
for word in data_list:
    if '@' in word:
        print(word)
```

You can later extract the email domain and name by spliting this loop result by '@' sign

Comment: Thank you,this helps! I think I am using find wrong, expecting it to find a match or whether something contains something, but really only getting the position of something. Your "if ... in" is really the correct approach to achieve that. Thanks again, lesson learned :)